# Before first section in a chapter, how to make numbering 1.x instead of 1.0.x?

Tags: sectioning, memoir

I am using the memoir class.

My document consists of chapters, which consist of sections.

Within sections, I want tables, figures, etc. to be numbered by chapter.section.number; e.g. Table 1.2.1 for the first table in Section 2 of Chapter 1.

If I have tables, lemmas, etc. in some introductory text of the chapter before the first section, I would like them to be labelled by chapter.number; e.g. Table 1.1.

Currently if I do this, I get Table 1.0.1 instead. I suppose it might be possible to do something like

```
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}}
```

at the beginning of the chapter and some other \renewcommand before the first section of the chapter, but is there any other way? Is there some built-in functionality e.g. in memoir to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Write the following code in the preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\ifnum\value{section}>0 \arabic{section}.\fi\arabic{table}}
```